# Registered view gets buggy when database link added

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-view, arcgis-10.7

I have a view in an Oracle 12c geodatabse:

```
create or replace view parcel_vw as (
select
    p.*
from
    parcel p
left join
    for_gis.gis_locations@gistomax loc  --<-- Join to database link
    on p.propertyid = loc.location
)

[there are 680 records in the view/fc]
```

The view has a **database link** to a table in a separate Oracle database.

- *Note: The join to the dblink does not propagate-out more records; the relationship is 1 to 1.*

---

This is what happens when I use the view in Arcmap 10.7.1:

1. Registered=n; dblink=y; WORKS
2. Registered=y; dblink=n; WORKS
3. Registered=y; dblink=y; **BUGGY**

---

In #3, when I try to select all features, I get buggy results:

- Occasionally: ArcMap crashes
- Consistently: Not all of the records can be selected with the select tool in the map.
- Consistently: None of the records can be selected in the attribute table with the Select All tool.

---

**Why does the view (with dblink) become buggy when registered with the geodatabase?**